# Как подключить yandex.map API к node.js

Tags: node.js, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Нужно сделать серверное приложение для нахождения автомобильного пути между координатами, но в документации нашел только примеры подключения через HTML. Пакет для npm тоже пока не получается найти

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для использования на сервере, действительно, нужно использовать HTTP API маршрутизатора. В линейке API Яндекса они есть, [вот тут список](https://yandex.ru/dev/routing/?from=SO).

JS API использовать на ноде не выйдет, в том числе юридически - ПС запрещает использовать API без показа карты на публичном сайте.